# Get a variable from SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, arrays, xml, variables, simplexml

How can I select the variable from this SimpleXMLElement?

If I type:

```
var_dump($var);
```

I get:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#7423 (2) {["@attributes"]=>array(1) {["type"]=>string(3) "119"}[0]=>string(12) "10869715.jpg"}
```

I need to get the result like "10869715.jpg".

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the original XML, it can be easier to see the structure.

Comment: Hi. Please have a look at [the examples in the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) and see what you can come up with. If you're still stuck, feel free to post a _specific_ question here with a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If I read your dump correctly, you don't need to do something special because your item is the top level item.

```
<?php

$xml = "
<item type='119'>10869715.jpg</item>
";

$element = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

echo ($element);
```

This would output:

```
10869715.jpg
```